# Using a sub var into other sub visual basic

Tags: vba, variables

How can i get a var value from a sub by calling it in other sub ? like

```
  Sub test()
    Dim a As Integer
    a = 1
  End Sub
  Sub testshow()
    MessageBox.Show(test.a)
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA (which your tag states) you need to change `Sub` into `Function` which will be:

```
Function test()
    Dim a As Integer
    a = 1
    test = a
End Function

Sub testshow()
   MsgBox test
End Sub
```

EDIT after comment: If you using more then one variable then:

```
Function test(whichVar)
    Dim a As Integer
    If whichVar = 1 then
        a = 100
    ElseIf whichVar = 2 Then
        a = 200
    'etc...
    End if

    test = a
End Function

Sub testshow()
   MsgBox test(2)    'will give you 200
End Sub
```

Comment: But if i'm using more than 1 var ?

Comment: Ok i understand, but my problem now is other... instand of var, i'm using rectangles, and i need to use their coordenats in other sub, like.
sub rect(byval ob as picturebox)
the code will draw 1 rectangle on each border of the 'ob'
end sub
sub colision()
gonna test if the rectgles colide with other objects
end sub
the problem is, i cant use the rect in the sub colision...

Comment: you have two possibilities- 1st. to use public var instead of local, 2nd. you could pass the rectangle object to function to make test. If you need precise information start new post and carefully describe that problem with rectangle. I'm sure we will help you...